# How to view db2 runtime errors using PHP?

Tags: php, db2, runtime-error, db2-400

I am using `db2_prepare()` and `db2_execute()` while passing my array of parameters as `db2_execute()`'s second parameter.  The `db2_prepare()` validates the syntax successfully, but `db2_execute()` returns false.  I'm assuming it is a data type conflict, but can't figure out for which field.

According to php.net `db2_stmt_error()` and `db2_stmt_errormsg()` report errors found by `db2_prepare()` or `db2_exec()` and not `db2_execute()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-stmt-error.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-stmt-errormsg.php

Is there a way to retrieve the exact query being executed with the values populated and all?  Is there a way to capture sql runtime errors from `db2_execute()`?